# Searching Thunderbird emails

Tags: thunderbird

I use Thunderbird to handle 5 email accounts.

When I use Global Search, I do not find a certain string. However, when I search through the Thuderbird data directory on on hard-drive, I do find the string.

This happens with unique words in subjects & mail body, and also with email addresses.

What I think is causing it is that I have been been using Thunderbird for at least 15 years, and have been transferring data from laptop to new laptop all that time.

The data are always in H:\email\thunderbird, so that when I search there on hard-drive, I find them.

But, when install Thunderbird on a new laptop and configure the accounts to use their respective folders under H:\email\thunderbird, I guess that Thunderbird does not import the existing emails, or maybe it just doesn't index them? I don't know, do you?

Question: how can I search for, and view, all of the emails currently on hard-drive from within Thunderbird?

I am guessing that I can import them somehow. That, of course, runs the danger of importing some that are already known (emails which arrived since I got the new laptop), but I seem to recall years ago using a plug-in to delete duplicate emails, so maybe I could use that to tidy up.

Before I start mucking about and possibly damaging things, can anyone tell, from my description, what is happening, and how best to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

First, if you copy *everything* from your Thunderbird profile folder to another PC using the same OS and same version of Thunderbird, *all* mail **that is in local folders** should be readable and searchable. [Moving between Windows and Linux is not as simple, I've found, perhaps due to line-end conventions.]

Second, are you searching within Thunderbird, or with an external tool such as the OS native search engine (e.g., Windows Search/Cortana) or with a third-party tool such as the excellent, free, [DocFetcher](http://docfetcher.sourceforge.net/en/index.html)? For *external* tools, in Thunderbird *Options [or Preferences] | General | System Integration*, check *Allow Windows Search to search messages*. This stores messages in plain text, which can be considered a reduction of security, but probably not an issue if you're the sole user.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Aha! these older messages are not in local folders. I have never used local folders, don't even understand them. I use only IMAP accounts. As I said, I _could_ maybe import the files on disk into TB & then delete any duplicates. What do you think?

Comment: Also, I want to search only from within Thunderbird, but have no objection to plugins (also, it's personal, but I dislike Windows search and/or anything that requires making index files).